# Trouble configuring Opscenter (5.1.1) Email alerts

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I was wondering if anyone could assist me in figuring out why my opscenter email alerts aren't working. My environment is docker running in native network mode with opscenter in a container. Everything is running on a private network but can communicate fine when testing with ping and telnet on SMTP. We configured the email.conf file to point at our internal mail-relay server that doesn't have any authentication. I have included the email.conf file below.

```
[email]
enabled=1
levels=
smtp_host=mail-relay.server
smtp_port=25
smtp_user=
smtp_pass=
smtp_use_ssl=0
smtp_use_tls=0
smtp_retries=1
smtp_timeout=5
to_addr=myemail@email.com
from_addr=arbitraryemail@email.com
subject=[{level_str}] OpsCenter Event on {cluster} - {message}
```

On a side note, I have been searching for some sort of log file that would possibly show me ANYTHING in regards to email... no such luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Logs for this are stored in below path : log_path=/data/data/opscenter/logs/opscenter/opscenterd.log